# Lesti FPC customer login/logout issue

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, customer-session

I recently started using Lesti FPC in one of my M1.9 sites and for the most part it works pretty well.

But I came across an issue with customer login/logout.

To better explain the issue, let's say there are 2 customers.

The 1st one logs in and searches for "PANTS" and gets some results, but then logs out and leaves the site.

Then the 2nd customer visits some product page (e.g. "T-SHIRT") and then logs in.

After logging in, he should be redirected back to the T-SHIRT product, but he's instead being redirected to the search results of the previous logged in customer.
So I presume that either the referrer url gets cached on the customer login form or the previous customer session gets cached and is then resumed after the 2nd customer logs in.

I've tried setting the customer_form_login block as lazy or dynamic and tried setting a refresh action customer_account_loginPost, but it's not working.
I've also tried various other combinations, but none have worked so far.

Any ideas what causes this issue or how to solve it?